# ASP.NET Core 6 [FromQuery] return null values when binding to object

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, .net-6.0, querystringparameter

A picture is worth a thousand words - as you can see in the following screenshots, I'm not able to retrieve the parameters in the query string and bind them to the `ApplyFilter` model. I've tried `[BindQuery]`, `[BindProperty]` and `[Bind]`, but unfortunately no luck at all. I keep getting null values on the filter parameter even though the parameters are passed to the `QueryString`.

```
https://localhost:7061/getallproducts?withproductoptions=true&categoryid=1&pricefrom=1&priceto=30&vendorname=ArtWithLight
```

Code:

```
public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IProductRepositery _prodRepo;

    public ProductsController(IProductRepositery prodRepo)
    {
        _prodRepo = prodRepo;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ProductDto>> GetAllProducts([FromQuery]ApplyFilter? filters)
    {
        return Ok(await _prodRepo.GetAllProductsAsync(filters));
    }
}

public class ApplyFilter
{
    public ApplyFilter()
    {
    }

    [FromQuery(Name = "categoryid")]
    List<int>? categoryIds { get; set; }
    [FromQuery(Name = "withproductoptions")]
    bool? withProductOptions { get; set; }
    [FromQuery(Name = "pricefrom")]
    decimal? priceFrom { get; set; }
    [FromQuery(Name = "priceto")]
    decimal? priceTo { get; set; }
    [FromQuery(Name = "vendorname")]
    string? vendorName { get; set; }
}
```

See screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qemMK.png

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "a picture worth a thousand words." Not on this site. Please read [ask], where it says "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question." and the FAQ [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Newbie here, thanks for the advice bud. Edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a go, have updated ApplyFilter() to use public properties.
Check out the ASP.NET Core 6.0 [Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#what-is-model-binding) section of the docs which explains how it works.

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] ApplyFilter filters)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    public class ApplyFilter
    {
        public List<int>? CategoryIds { get; set; }
        public bool? WithProductOptions { get; set; }
        public decimal? PriceFrom { get; set; }
        public decimal? PriceTo { get; set; }
        public string? VendorName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Request example:

```
/Products?CategoryIds=1&CategoryIds=2&WithProductOptions=true&PriceFrom=10&PriceTo=20&VendorName=The%20Vendor
```

Comment: Worked just fine mate, thanks a lot. its strange thou that a variable starting with small letter is causing this ?

Comment: No worries @AbedAjarmeh good to hear. I've clarified the answer a bit, it wasn't being caused by the camelCase property names!